# How do I get Jest to catch the thrown error as expected?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, try-catch, throw

I am attempting to write some tests in Jest and keep getting the below result. How do I get Jest to catch the thrown error as expected?
Code:

```
test("Test that TEXT_PROPERTIES can throw a typeError", () => {
  function testError() {
    try {
      throw new TypeError(`why doesn't this work`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  expect(() => {
    testError();
  }).toThrow();
});
```

Result:

```
  × Test that TEXT_PROPERTIES can throw a typeError (11 ms)

  ● Test that TEXT_PROPERTIES can throw a typeError

    expect(received).toThrow()

    Received function did not throw

      62 |   expect(() => {
      63 |     testError();
    > 64 |   }).toThrow();
         |      ^
      65 | });
      66 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/components/typography/typography.test.js:64:6)

  console.error
    TypeError: why doesn't this work
```

I have read a bunch of other "answers" to this question but none of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testError` does not throw an error to the outside world because of try-catch block. From the perspective of Jest's expect, `testError` returns undefined and not an exception (error). Here's a similar test:

```js
function testError() {
  try {
    throw new TypeError(`why doesn't this work`);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

var result = testError();
console.log(result); // undefined
console.log(result instanceof TypeError); // false
```

Change the function to this:

```
function testError() {
    throw new TypeError(`why doesn't this work`);
}
```

```js
function testError() {
  throw new TypeError(`why doesn't this work`);
}

// We want to use try-catch to encapsulate the error
try {
  result();
} catch (e){
  console.log(e); // undefined
  console.log(e instanceof TypeError); // false
  console.log(e instanceof TypeError); // false
}
```

Comment: This prevents the error from being caught at runtime.

Comment: @TimMartin, I would recommend testing the functions then. AFAIK, Jest works on the premise of what a function returns and compares the output against predefined expected output.

Comment: I see you updated your answer, thanks but moving the try-catch block outside the function call makes what i'm trying to test pointless. I'll have to re-evaluate how i am approaching these tests.